# How to properly link GLAD/GLFW with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been trying to set up and configure a window with a an opengl context for a few days and I am stuck on getting it working with CMake. I am unable to include glad/glfw in a subdirectory, but am able to include it on my src directory. I am new to CMake so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is my file structure:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
├── build.sh
├── configure.sh
├── lib
│   └── external
│       ├── glad
│       │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       │   ├── include
│       │   └── src
│       └── glfw
│           ├── CMake
│           ├── CMakeLists.txt
│           ├── CONTRIBUTORS.md
│           ├── LICENSE.md
│           ├── README.md
│           ├── deps
│           ├── docs
│           ├── examples
│           ├── include
│           ├── src
│           └── tests
├── run.sh
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Engine
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── gameManager.cpp
    │   └── gameManager.h
    ├── Entities
    ├── RenderEngine
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   ├── displayManager.cpp
    │   └── displayManager.h
    └── main.cpp
```

I am trying to include glad/glfw in displayManager.h, but am getting the error "cannot open source file "glad/glad.h" and "cannot open source file GLFW/glfw3.h"

**Top level CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.0)
project(Opengl_tut VERSION 0.1.0)


# For loop add subdirectories
foreach (sub "src" "${GLFW_DIR}" "${GLAD_DIR}" "src/RenderEngine")
    add_subdirectory("${sub}")
endforeach ()
```

**lib/external/glad/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25.0)
project(Glad)

add_library(glad include/glad/glad.h src/glad.c)
target_include_directories(glad PUBLIC include/)
```

**lib/external/glfw/CMakeLists.txt**
This is the same one found on the github repository (standard one) here: https://github.com/glfw/glfw

**src/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

# Get these files
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    glfw
    glad
)
```

This allows me to #include <glad/glad.h> and <GLFW/glfw3.h> inside of main.cpp, so I tried doing something similar inside of the displayManager level CMakeLists

**src/RenderEngine/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(displayManager "displayManager.cpp" "displayManager.h")

# Get these files
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    glfw
    glad
)
```

How do I get the displayManager.h file to recognize glad/glfw? I also will need to #include "displayManager.h" inside of src/Engine/gameManager.h, will that follow the same solution?

Comment: "How do I get the displayManager.h file to recognize glad/glfw?" - A compiler adds include directories not for the **header** but for the **source**. If you want to compile `main.cpp` and resolve `#include <glad/glad.h>` during that **compilation**, you link the target `Opengl_tut` which is build from `main.cpp`: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw glad)`. If you want to resolve this include when compile `displayManager.cpp`, you link the target `displayManager`. If you want to resolve this include when compile `engine.cpp`, then you need to link target which contains that source.